# Determine POIs with Proximity Alerts and get their distance to the current position

Tags: android, geofencing

It's me again having another problem with my location app. Let me explain the current situation:

I have a file stored on my SD card which contains various combinations of latitudes and longitudes in order to define different POIs. These are read into an ArrayList and added to the map using markers. Also, proximity alerts are added. Whenever the user gets near a POI, he is notified using a BroadcastReceiver. This is working perfectly fine.

Now, what I want to do is display a message to the user when he is 1 mile, 0.5 miles and 0.1 miles away from the POI.

What I can do is use the distanceTo() method in the onReceive() method of the BroadcastReceiver. But this will only work once, when the user enters the radius. But since I need the distance to be updated regularly depending on the current position, this won't help me out.

My idea is to give back the latitude and longitude of the POI. Whenever the user enters the specified radius, an Intent is fired from the BroadcastReceiver to the Activity (which is my MainActivity that added the proximity alerts). Then, in my Activity, I get the latitude and longitude and continue my distance calculation in the onLocationChanged method.

Unfortunately, my idea isn't working. It just gives me loop and then my mobile phone kind of freezes. Here are some code snippets:

In my MainActivity:

```
private void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, int id) {

        // +++ Add a proximity alert to the corresponding obstacle +++ \\

        // Attach the id of the obstacle (its index in the ArrayList) to an intent
        // NOTE: This is needed in order to distinguish between all proximity alerts added
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        intent.putExtra("key_id", id);
        intent.putExtra("key_latitude", latitude);
        intent.putExtra("key_longitude", longitude);
        intent.putExtra("key_current_location", mCurrentLocation);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // Add the proximity alert
        mLocationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, Constants.POINT_RADIUS, Constants.PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, proximityIntent);
    }

...

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, counter + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // +++ Adapt mCurrentLatitude and mCurrentLongitude when position changes +++ \\
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mCurrentLatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
    mCurrentLongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

    if(counter == 2) {
        Intent fromReceiver = getIntent();

        if (fromReceiver.getDoubleExtra("key_dest_latitude", 12345) != 12345.0) {

            double latitude = fromReceiver.getDoubleExtra("key_dest_latitude", 12345);
            double longitude = fromReceiver.getDoubleExtra("key_dest_longitude", 12345);

            Toast.makeText(this, "RECEIVER: LAT =" + latitude + " & LONG = " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NOT AVAILABLE YET", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In the class of the BroadcastReceiver:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // +++ Check if a geofence is entered +++ \\

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
    mEntering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if (mEntering == true) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Obstacle " + intent.getIntExtra("key_id", 666) + " in less than " + Constants.POINT_RADIUS + "m!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent fromReceiver = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        fromReceiver.putExtra("key_dest_latitude", intent.getDoubleExtra("key_latitude", 0));
        fromReceiver.putExtra("key_dest_longitude", intent.getDoubleExtra("key_longitude", 0));
        fromReceiver.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(fromReceiver);

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Leaving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

I'm thankful for any suggestions in order to solve my problem. I just can't find a solution for that...

Comment: I guess another approach would be adding 3 proximity alerts, each with another radius (1mile, 0.5 miles and 0.1 miles) to a POI. But that seems very inefficient to me, especially if there are an unknown amount of POIs.